# Compact operators, injectivity and closed range

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a an infinite dimensional Banach space. $A\in B(X)$ is a compact operator. If its range $\operatorname{Im}(A)$ is closed in $X$ then $A$ cannot be injective because $A:X\to \operatorname{Im}(A)$ would be a compact bijection between Banach spaces and the unit ball $B_X=A^{-1}AB_X$ would be compact.

Now if $A$ is not injective, can we say that $\operatorname{Im}(A)$ must be closed ? Or if this is false, can we find a non injective compact operator with non closed range (i.e. infinite dimensional range) ?

Comment: Note that "closed" and "finite dimensional" are not the same thing. There exist infinite dimensional subspaces that are closed, as well as infinite dimensional subspaces that are not.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro But I think "closed" and "finite dimensional" range are the same thing for a compact operator in Banach spaces.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I also updated the example in my answer, now it should match your question better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the operator $T\colon \ell^2\to \ell^2$ defined by 
$$ T\mathbf{x}=\left(0, \frac{x_2}{2}, \frac{x_3}{3}\ldots\right).$$
$T$ is not injective because $T\mathbf{e}_1=0$, but it is compact and its range is the subspace 
$$E=\left\{\mathbf{y}\in \ell^2\ :\ y_1=0,\ (ny_n)\in \ell^2.\right\}.$$
The subspace $E$ is dense in $M=\overline{\mathrm{span}}\{\mathbf{e}_2, \mathbf{e}_3\ldots\}$, because it contains $\{\mathbf{e}_2, \mathbf{e}_3, \ldots\}$, but the inclusion $E\subset M$ is proper. For example, the sequence 
$$\mathbf{x}=\begin{cases} 
0, & n=1 \\ 
\frac{1}{n}, & n \ge 2 
\end{cases}$$
does not belong to $E$. Therefore $E$ is not closed in $M$, hence it is not closed in $\ell^2$ too.

---

**P.S.** In comments the OP requested an example in $C([0,1])$ space. This of course is more complicated because we have now left the elementary Hilbert space setting. Indeed, I am not able to furnish an example, nor I think that a *natural* example exists. Let me explain what *natural* means to me in this context.

The typical examples of compact operators in $C([0,1])$ space are integral transforms 
$$Tf=\int_0^1 K(x, y) f(y)\, dy. $$
In turn, integral transforms usually arise as solution operators to linear boundary value problems for ODEs: 
$$\begin{cases} Lu = f, & x\in (0, 1) \\ U(u)=0\end{cases}$$ Here $L$ is a symmetric linear differential operator and $U(u)=0$ denotes the boundary conditions. (Notation is taken from Coddington-Levinson's book on ordinary differential equations, chapter 7). Now such an operator is always injective, as $Tf=0$ means that the solution to the boundary value problem is the null function $u=0$, which forces $f=Lu=L0=0$. So an example cannot come from there.

There are also integral transforms $T$ that do *not* come from a boundary value problem, of course. However, the typical examples here have splitting kernel:
$$K(x, y)=\sum_{j=1}^J a_j(x)b_j(y). $$
This splitting leads to operators with finite dimensional range. So an example cannot come from there either.

That's what I meant with *natural* above. But there are a lot more compact operators on $C([0, 1])$. I am sure that an example of an operator which is compact, not injective, and not finite rank can be easily crafted, perhaps with tools of abstract functional analysis (such as Schauder bases).

Comment: What I want is a compact non injective operator with non closed range.

Comment: Ok. A small modification of this example will do.

Comment: @user144542: Now it should be OK.

Comment: That answers my question, thank you.

Comment: Can we find an example in the space $X=C[0,1]$ of continuous real function on $[0,1]$ ? Every time I find a compact operator on $X$ which is not injective, I see its range and I find it closed (finite dimensional), that's the reason behind my question here. Or maybe this deserves to be in a new question.

Comment: @user144542: I am adding a PS to this answer.

Comment: Thank you for all these details !!

Comment: @user144542: You are welcome. It might be interesting to ask another question, to search for a more or less explicit example in $C([0,1])$ space. As I said, I believe that *natural* examples in this setting are either injective or finite rank, as you have rightfully observed. However, abstract functional analysis is a powerful machine that can go far beyond "natural" things. I am not an expert on that, but on this site there are some, and their opinion surely is interesting.

Answer (score 4):

A compact linear operator $A\colon X \to Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces, has closed range if and only if it has finite rank.

Because if the range is closed, it is a Banach space, and the open mapping theorem asserts that $A(B_X)$ is a neighbourhood of $0$. But its closure is compact, so $\mathcal{R}(A)$ is locally compact. By Riesz' theorem, a Hausdorff topological vector space is locally compact if and only if it is finite-dimensional.

Comment: I know this, this is actually what I said in the last line of the original post. Maybe my question is miss-understood.

Comment: The point is that injectivity has absolutely nothing to do with it. You ask "Now if $A$ is not injective, can we say that $Im(A)$ must be closed ?" And I say: "No, the range is closed if and only if it is finite-dimensional, regardless of whether the operator is injective".

Comment: I thought there was a link to injectivity because: a compact operator $A$ with closed range cannot be injective.

Comment: Well, unless the domain is finite-dimensional. A compact operator has closed range if and only if its kernel has finite codimension.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I am now satisfied with the counterexample given by Giuseppe Negro.

Comment: @DanielFischer: The OP has noticed a lack of examples of compact non-injective operators on $C([0,1])$ space, except the ones with finite-dimensional range. I have tried to give an interpretation of this apparent phenomenon in my answer. Would you like to have a look, please?