# Injectivity of the operator $(Ax)(t)=\int_0 ^1 k(s,t) x(s)ds$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X=C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ (equipped with the supremum norm). Let $A$ be the operator defined for each $x\in X$ by
$$(Ax)(t)=\int_0 ^1 k(s,t) x(s)ds,$$
where $k:[0,1]\times [0,1]\to \mathbb{R} $ is continuous.

Can we find a sufficient condition on $k$ to make $A$ injective ?

Comment: A sufficient condition is that the family of functions $\{s\mapsto k(s,t): t\in [0,1]\}$ has dense linear span in $L^2[0,1]$. I imagine this condition is not   easy to check, though.

Comment: Not an answer but *maybe* useful: A sufficient condition surely is that $k$ be a Green's function (typically denoted by $G$). (Related to the discussion we had in [the other question of yours](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/807176/8157)). I *think* that Green's functions can be characterized as the functions that decompose as follows: $$ G(x, y) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mu_k \Phi_j (x) \Phi_j(y),$$ where $\mu_j$ is real and tends to $0$ and $\Phi_j$ is a complete orthonormal system consisting of smooth functions. I am not entirely sure, though. Moreover, this is probably not a real answer

Comment: Fourier Kernel should be another example. $$k(s,t) = \exp(j2\pi st)$$

Comment: for  a  related  MO  post  see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/243425/infinite-dimensional-version-of-a-simple-fact-on-certain-singular-matrices

Answer (score 7):

An easy one is $k(x,t)=k(x-t)$, and the (1 periodic) fourier series of $K$ has only non zero coefficients.

Indeed, by linearity it is enough to show that $Ax=0$ implies $x=0$. Now,
$x$ let us compute the fourier coefficients of $Ax$. We have

$$
\hat{Ax}(n)=\int_0^1 Ax e^{-i2\pi n x}{\rm d}x=\int_0^1\int_0^1 k(x-t)x(t)e^{-i2\pi n t}e^{-i2\pi n (x-t)} {\rm d}x {\rm d}t
$$
(as $\exp(-i2\pi n t)\exp({-i2\pi n (x-t)})=\exp(-2\pi nx)$). Changing variables to $t=t$, $u=x-t$, we obtain 
$$
\hat{Ax}(n)=\int_0^1 \int_0^1k(u)\exp({-i2\pi n u})x(t)\exp(-i2\pi n t){\rm d}u{\rm d}t
$$
and this last expression is just the product of two integrals, namely
$$
\hat{Ax}(n)=\hat{k}(n)\hat{x}(n).
$$
Therefore, if for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, $\hat{k}(n)\neq0$, then $Ax=0$ implies $\hat{x}(n)=0$ for all $n$. Then Parseval's Theorem shows that  $\int_0^1 x^2(t)dt=0$, and therefore, as $x$ is continuous, $x\equiv0$.

Comment: Can you add some details please ?

Comment: @Edwin  I edited the question to include the details